# In iphone what is the element called that slides up from the bottom of the screen with multiple choices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, element

In iphone what is the element called that slides up from the bottom of the screen with multiple choices?

Sometimes it is used to confirm a delete, sometimes it provides options for sharing.
It has multiple buttons stretching across the width screen, and when it rolls up it dims the rest of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called a UIActionSheet.

Here is an implementation example:

http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/

Answer (score 2):

That's a UIActionSheet.  The documentation for it is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActionSheet).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you're asking about [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I think you are referring to a `UIActionSheet`. There are many examples online of how to use this, and the documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You could also mean a `UIAlertView`. The documentation for that can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html). Hope that helps!